# How to test if double can be moduled using java

Tags: java, double, modulo

I have list of double values.

Like this:

```
0.4997
0.4998
0.4999
0.5
0.5001
0.5002
0.5003
0.5004
1.0
```

And I want print all numbers which can be modulet (`%`) by 0.5.

But standar modulo operation - `value % 0.5` not working. How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe multiply it by 10,100, or 1000. Do % by 5,50, or 500. Then divide again by 10, 100 or 1000 to get back the original number.

Comment: Divide everyone by 0.5 and verify the decimal part...

Comment: But, BTW, I tried it (% 0.5), and its working.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi I thought similarly as you did, about multiplying with 10 and then % 5. Nice idea bro